# 18.04 Core: RaspberryPi 4 install requires SSH key to add to SSO

Tags: ssh, raspberrypi, ubuntu-core, single-sign-on

Noob here to the ssh world. I'm trying to install Ubuntu Core 18.04 LTS on a new Raspberry Pi 4; I flashed a copy of the [image from raspberry pi's site](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi-core).

Instructions say [I need a SSH key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) , but I can't follow the steps because I don't have a window to create one in the system I'm actually installing.

I'm confused, and lost. What do I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi-core tells us you need to create an Ubuntu Single-SignOn (SSO) account, which you make at https://login.ubuntu.com/ unless you already have one.

Then, following https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys , you can import the ssh key into your SSO account.

If you've never made one, then install [ssh-keygen](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/) here to make one, then move it over to the Raspberry Pi on a USB flash drive, by carving it onto a stone tablet, skywriting, or another transfer method of your choice.